# Where does Picasa save the edits I make to images?

Tags: images, picasa

I am using Picasa to edit my images. After I fixed a bunch of images I looked at them by browsing my file system and find they are all in their original state. I wanted to find them in their altered state with the edits I made in Picasa.

I want to back them up as well as send them for printing. But I don't want to do this with the originals, only the edited up versions.

How do I access the edited versions of the images?

When I look at old albums in Picasa, they persisted the edits from when I made them, but when I look at the file on disk it's not the same.

Comment: Did you click the save/apply button in Picasa?

Comment: i just make the edits and click the right button to move to the next image

Comment: when i look at old albums in picasa they persisted the edits from when i made them, but when i look at the file on disk its not the same. so picasa has to save this somewhere...

Answer (score 8):

[From the Picasa Help page:](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=11021)

> **Saving Edits: Saving photos**
>
> Picasa is designed to keep your
>   original photos safe when you save
>   your photo edits. This is done by
>   creating a new JPEG file that's a copy
>   of the original with your edits
>   applied. The original photo is never
>   altered, but depending on how you save
>   the file, its location on your hard
>   drive may change. Here's a brief
>   overview of the different save options
>   in Picasa, based on how they affect
>   the location of your original photos.
>
> **Move your original photo**
>
> When you use the Save to Disk  and the
>   File > Save options, Picasa creates a
>   copy of your photo with all edits
>   applied and moves the original to a
>   subfolder called '.picasaoriginals'.
>   This subfolder is hidden on your
>   computer and isn't visible in Picasa.
>   This automatic backup lets you undo or
>   revert your saves.
>
> - Save to Disk
> - File > Save
>
> **Keep your original photo in its
>   current location**
>
> Unlike Save to Disk and the File >
>   Save function, the following options
>   don't move your original photos. These
>   options create and save a new copy of
>   your photo with all edits applied,
>   leaving your original photo unmoved.
>   The new copy with edits applied is
>   saved to a different location
>   depending on the option you choose.
>
> - Export
> - File > Save a Copy
> - File > Save As

Comment: Next time please leave some more info @kacalapy and use comments to reply to others

Answer (score 1):

After editing your pic in Picasa, click on "file" in the upper left corner of your screen, scroll down & click on "save a copy". This will add the edited version of your picture in your original picture file next to the original picture. You can go back to all the pictures you previously edited & click on each one "Edit in Picasa". This will pull up your previously edited version, then you can simply click on "file" & "save a copy".

Answer (score 1):

On saving the edited pictures Picasa will overwrite your picture with the edited version. At the same time the originals will be preserved by Picasa in the same directory in a hidden folder named ".picasaoriginals".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe Picasa makes a folder in the original  folder in which the images are located and the edits are stored ( It also might be a hidden folder , dont exactly remember as i havent used picasa in a long time , but I am sure the edits are in a sub folder)

Comment: Comment by @kacalapy: @shark its actually the other way around. also i was sorry to learn that all my images for the past few years didnt have the edits saved and are now lost and all i have are the originals because i didnt hit save.